# ImportError: No module named requests: But it is installed already

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, atom-editor

I am trying to learn web-scraping using Python and installed Requests using

```
pip3 install requests
```

and checked again using the same command. I got the following output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
```

But when I tried to execute the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open('/home/aca/Documents/Python files/test.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

in Atom v 1.26.1, I received the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aca/Documents/Python files/experiment.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
[Finished in 0.167s]
```

I confirmed the installation of Requests in IDLE by importing it using the Python shell and task completed without ImportError.

I am stuck at this point. Is this an issue of an older version  Atom? If yes please suggest a lightweight ide for lubuntu 18.04.

Comment: ATOM isn't an IDE, it's "A hackable text editor" according to the site. There's a big difference; That there are some similar features shows how powerful Atom is. Also, asking for recommendations for programs, libraries, packages is off-topic for SO and will get your question closed. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking your Python versions. It's quite possible that you have Requests installed in one interpreter, while Atom uses another.

Run your script directly in the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have more than one version of Python installed?

Try this:

```
python3.6 -m pip install requests
```

You can also verify that Atom has selected the right interpreter when running this `experiment.py` script.

Answer (score 1):

If the normal pip3 command won't work, try

```
sudo python3 -m pip install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

I did

`python -m pip install requests`

this will add `requests` module to the location where your python version is installed.

then import requests module in your views.py using this command

`import requests`

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for the edits